# VBA filter table and copy cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below. The task I am trying to perform is:

1. Filter table for rows that contain 'yes' in column C
2. Copy the cell to the left of every yes to another location (all pasted in one column, each on a new row)
3. Remove filter and return sheet to pre-filtered state

The code below filters the list, but then copies all of the filtered table. How can I adjust it to only copy what is stated above

Thanks!

```
Sub filter_me()

With Sheets("Trader")
    .Range("B8:B22").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="yes"
    .AutoFilter.Range.Copy
  End With
With Sheets("SHEET2")
    .Range("B1").PasteSpecial
  End With
With Sheets("Trader")
     ActiveSheet.Range("B8:B22").AutoFilter
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do it for you as written:

```
Sub filter_me()

Dim wsTrader as Worksheet
Set wsTrader = Worksheets("Trader")

With wsTrader

    .Range("B8:B22").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="yes"
    .Range("A8:A22").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'copy filtered cells 1 column to left

   Worksheets("SHEET2").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    .Range("B8:B22").AutoFilter

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a as integer
Dim YesNoCol as Integer
Dim DataCol as Integer
Dim TargetCol as Integer

YesNoCol = 5
DataCol = 4
TargetCol = 8

' change rows as necessary
For a = 8 to 22
    If Ucase(ActiveSheet.Cells(a, YesNoCol).Value) = YES Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(a, DataCol).Value = _
            ActiveSheet.Cells(a, TargetCol).Value
    End If
Next a
```

Does this do it for you?  Sorry, I did this on my phone from memory.

Comment: Hi, none of these seem to work. I have adjusted the code to the below but it still does not copy and paste it

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this and tweak it as per your requirement if required.

```
Sub filter_me()
Dim sws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set sws = Sheets("Trader")
Set dws = Sheets("Sheet2")
'Clearing Sheet2 before pasting the autofiltered data
dws.Cells.Clear

'Clearing existing filter on Trader sheet
sws.AutoFilterMode = False

'Assuming Row8 is header row
With sws.Rows(8)
    'filtering column C
    .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="yes"
    'checking if any data is returned after applying the autofilter
    If sws.Range("A8:A22").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1 Then
        'copying the filtered data from column A:B along with headers onto Sheet2 in B1
        sws.Range("A8:B22").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dws.Range("B1")
    End If
    .AutoFilter
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy/paste headers, too;

```
Sub Main()
    With Worksheets("Trader").Range("C8:C22")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1 Criteria1:="yes"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Offset(,-1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

While If you want to copy/paste filtered data without header row:

```
Sub Main()
    With Worksheets("Trader").Range("C8:C22")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1 Criteria1:="yes"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Offset(1,-1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @gekko2670, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copy()

Dim a As Integer
Dim YesNoCol As Integer
Dim DataCol As Integer
Dim TargetCol As Integer

YesNoCol = 3
DataCol = 2
TargetCol = 1

' change rows as necessary
For a = 8 To 22
If UCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(a, YesNoCol).Value) = YES Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(a, DataCol).Value.copy
        ActiveSheet.Cells(a, TargetCol).Paste
End If
Next a

End Sub
```